# Batch operations on restapi from angular

Tags: json, angular, httpclient, rest

I wanted to do the bulk operations on my JSON from angular using httpclient. But when I am doing it it's unable to update the JSON rather it's only updating the last checked record.

Need your support to fix the code.

*I think I need to write a bulk operation in services similar to updateUser carrying multiple records and post to service.*

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class CommonService {

  constructor(private http:HttpClient) { }

  createUser(user: any) {
    return this.http.post("http://localhost:3000/users", user);
  }

  getAllUser() {
    return this.http.get("http://localhost:3000/users");
  }

  updateUser(user: any): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.put("http://localhost:3000/users/" + user.id, user);
  }

  deleteUser(user: any) {
    return this.http.delete("http://localhost:3000/users/" + user.id);
  }

}
```

app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonService } from './common.service';
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})

export class AppComponent {
  title = 'db-poc1';
  allUser: any;
  isEdit = false;
  isView = false;
  isBatchEdit = false;
  totalRecords: any;
  page: Number = 1;
  currentImpact: string = '';

  userObj = {
    id: '', first_name: '', last_name: '', email: '', gender: '', ip_address: '', impact: ''
  }

  impactCount = {
    applicable: 0, notapplicable: 0, fyi: 0 
  }

  batchUpdateUsers = [];

  constructor(private commonService: CommonService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getLatestUser();
  }
  
  checkboxClicked() {
    this.batchUpdateUsers = this.allUser.filter(row => row.checked);
    this.isView  = false;
    this.isBatchEdit = this.batchUpdateUsers.length > 0;
    this.currentImpact = this.userObj.impact;
  }

  addUser(formObj: any) {
    this.commonService.createUser(formObj).subscribe((response) => {
      this.getLatestUser();
    })
  }

  getLatestUser() {
    this.commonService.getAllUser().subscribe((response) => {
      this.allUser = response;
      this.totalRecords = this.allUser.length;
      this.getApplicableCounts();
      this.allUser.forEach(row => row.checked = false);
    })
  }

  getApplicableCounts() {
    this.impactCount = {applicable: 0,notapplicable: 0,fyi: 0}
    this.allUser.forEach(row => {
      if (row.impact === 'Applicable') {
        this.impactCount.applicable++;
      } else if (row.impact === 'Not Applicable') {
         this.impactCount.notapplicable++;
      } else if (row.impact === 'FYI') {
        this.impactCount.fyi++;
      }
    });
  }

  editUser(user: any) {
    this.isEdit = true;
    this.userObj = user;
    this.allUser.forEach(user => user.checked = false);
    this.currentImpact = user.impact;
  }

  deleteUser(user: any) {
    this.commonService.deleteUser(user).subscribe(() => {      
      this.getLatestUser();
    })
  }

  updateUser() {
    this.isEdit = !this.isEdit;
    this.userObj.impact = this.currentImpact;
    this.commonService.updateUser(this.userObj).subscribe(() => {
      this.getLatestUser();
    })
    this.getApplicableCounts();
  }

  cancelEdit() {
    this.isEdit = false;
    this.isView = false;
  }

  viewUser(user: any) {
    this.isView = true;
    this.userObj = user;
  }

  cancelBatchEdit() {
    this.isBatchEdit = false;
    this.allUser.forEach(user => {user.checked = false});
  }

  batchUpdateUser() {
    this.isBatchEdit = false;
    const batchUpdateUserList = [];
    this.allUser.forEach(user => {
      if (user.checked) {
        user.impact = this.currentImpact
        batchUpdateUserList.push(user);
        user.checked = false;
      }
    });

    this.commonService.updateUser(this.userObj).subscribe(() => {
      this.getLatestUser();
    })

    this.getApplicableCounts();
  }

}
```

app.component.html

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="text-right toal-records">Total: {{totalRecords}}</div>
      <div style="padding-left: 20px">
        Male: {{genderCount.male}} 
        Female: {{genderCount.female}}
        Other: {{genderCount.other}}</div>
      <div style="padding-left: 20px">
        Applicable: {{impactCount.applicable}}
        Not Applicable: {{impactCount.notApplicable}}
        FYI: {{impactCount.fyi}}
      </div>
      <table class="table table-sm table-responsive">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th *ngIf="!isEdit">Edit</th>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Gender</th>
            <th>ID Address</th>
    <th>Impact</th>  
    <th></th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr class="record-row" (click)="viewUser(user)" *ngFor="let user of allUser">
    <input *ngIf="!isEdit" [(ngModel)]="user.checked" type="checkbox" (change)="checkboxClicked()">
    <td>{{user.first_name}}</td>
    <td>{{user.last_name}}</td>
    <td>{{user.email}}</td>
    <td>{{user.gender}}</td>
    <td>{{user.ip_address}}</td>
    <td>{{user.impact}}</td>
    <td>
      <button *ngIf="!isEdit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" (click)="editUser(user)" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModel">Edit</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>

<div *ngIf="isView" class="view-details">
  <ul>
    <li>First Name: {{userObj.first_name}}</li>
    <li>Last Name: {{userObj.last_name}}</li>
    <li>Email: {{userObj.email}}</li>
    <li>Gender: {{userObj.gender}}</li>
    <li>IP Address: {{userObj.ip_address}}</li>
    <li>Impact: {{userObj.impact}}</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div *ngIf="isBatchEdit && !isEdit">    
<form #myForm="ngForm">
      <div class="form-group">
    <select name="impact" class="form-control form-control-sm" [(ngModel)]="currentImpact">
      <option>Applicable</option>
      <option>Not Applicable</option>
      <option>FYI</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <button type="button" (click)="batchUpdateUser()" class="btn btn-success btn-sm btn-update mr-2">
    Update
    </button>
  <button type="button" (click)="cancelBatchEdit()" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm">Cancel</button>
</form>        
  </div>

<div *ngIf="isEdit">    
<form #myForm="ngForm">
      <div class="form-group">
    <select name="impact" class="form-control form-control-sm" [(ngModel)]="currentImpact">
      <option>Applicable</option>
      <option>Not Applicable</option>
      <option>FYI</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <button type="button" (click)="updateUser()" class="btn btn-success btn-sm btn-update mr-2" >Update</button>
  <button type="button" (click)="cancelEdit()" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm">Cancel</button>
</form>        
  </div>
</div>
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-bsrwmh?file=src/app/app.component.html

Comment: what are you trying to accomplish here? the stackblitz seems to be working fine

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you need to *batch* user updates. which confirms that in the API side there must be a way to update multiple users at once. with that assumption here is my answer.

You can add this method in `commonService` and just pass in the list of total users that you want update.

```
  batchUpdateUsers(users: any[], batchSize = 10): Observable<void> {
    const batches = [];
    let offset = 0;
    while (offset < users.length) {
      batches.push(
        users.slice(offset, offset + batchSize)
      );
      offset += batchSize;
    }
    return forkJoin(
      batches.map(batch => this.http.put("http://localhost:3000/batchUserUpdate", batch))
    );
  }
```

Note: `/batchUserUpdate` , there must be some kind of API that accepts multiple user updates.

**If in case you dont have such a `batchUserUpdate` api, you can replace the return statement with the following,**

```
return forkJoin(
  users.map(user => this.updateUser(user))
);
```

Comment: will this will be same for select all option? or do i need to add a new function?

Comment: As far as this function goes, you pass in the total list of users that needs updating. it can be selectAll users, or select just few user etc... it should work,.

Comment: faisd mpm how do i create select all function n update batchuser?

Comment: Not sure that I understand your question. And moreover if my response answered the original question please mark it as accepted answer. Also, if you have anyother new question like the one you are trying to ask. Please post a new one. Thanks.

Comment: can you help me to get answer of this question please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65350436/how-can-i-get-the-count-of-specific-nested-node-in-json-using-typescript-in-angu