# How can I get the count of specific nested node in json using typescript in angular?

Tags: json, angular, typescript

I need to get the count of specific nested nodes from the JSON. I am trying to figure it out but unable to get the specific result as it's showing me the total count of all Applicable, Not Applicable under all rows instead of specific nested node count.

Required your expertise to rectify the code to achieve the desired result.

Current Output:

```
Applicable as 3, Not Applicable as 2
```

Expected Output:
I am displaying the parent rows and a click function on each row to display the details/entire data. So, for the first row in details, I want
Applicable: 2, Not Applicable: 1
2nd Row click
Applicable: 1, Not Applicable: 1

[image]
clicking on 1st row
[image]
clicking on 2nd row
[image]

for both showing the total count. rather it should show for 1st only 2 n 1 and for 2nd only 1 n 1.

app.component.ts

```
getApplicableCounts() {
    this.impactCount = {applicable:0, notapplicable:0, fyi: 0}
    this.allUser.forEach(row => {
      row.assigned_to.forEach(sub => {
        if (sub.sub_impact === 'Applicable') {
          this.impactCount.applicable++;
        } else if (sub.sub_impact === 'Not Applicable') {
           this.impactCount.notapplicable++;
        } else if (sub.sub_impact === 'FYI') {
          this.impactCount.fyi++;
        }
      });
    });
  }
```

app.component.html

```
<ul class="">
<li class="">{{impactCount.applicable}}</li>
<li class="">{{impactCount.notapplicable}}</li>
<li class="">{{impactCount.fyi}}</li>
</ul>
```

data.json

```
{
  "users": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "first_name": "Male",
      "last_name": "Record",
      "email": "male.record@gmail.com",
      "gender": "Male",
      "dob": "01-01-1987",
      "impact": "Not Applicable",
      "score": "Updated",
      "checked": false,
      "assigned_to": [
        {
          "co_score": 54,
          "dl": "CAT1",
          "sub_impact": "Applicable",
          "comments": "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book."
        },
        {
          "co_score": 20,
          "dl": "CAT2",
          "sub_impact": "Not Applicable",
          "comments": "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book."
        },
        {
          "co_score": 99,
          "dl": "CAT1",
          "sub_impact": "Applicable",
          "comments": "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book."
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "first_name": "Female",
      "last_name": "Record",
      "email": "female.record@gmail.com",
      "gender": "Female",
      "dob": "31-12-1987",
      "impact": "Not Applicable",
      "checked": false,
      "score": "Updated",
      "assigned_to": [
        {
          "co_score": 54,
          "dl": "CAT1",
          "sub_impact": "Applicable",
          "comments": "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book."
        },
        {
          "co_score": 20,
          "dl": "CAT2",
          "sub_impact": "Not Applicable",
          "comments": "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book."
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the help of a function in the component to achieve the desired behavior,

component.ts:

```
getCount(members, filterValue) {
  return members.filter(a => a.sub_impact === filterValue).length;
}
```

and the html would look as follows:

```
<li>Applicable: {{ getCount(userObj.assigned_to, 'Applicable') }}</li>
<li>Not Applicable: {{ getCount(userObj.assigned_to, 'Not Applicable') }}</li>
<li>FYI: {{ getCount(userObj.assigned_to, 'FYI') }}</li>
```

here is a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-6qqhii?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) with the example

There are more robust ways of doing this, like creating a [pipe](https://angular.io/guide/pipes), which can make the code more elegant, but this method is also fine, since no code duplication exists and it works as intended in a clear, explicit way.

Comment: can I also assign the same to `<li [style.width]="{{ getCount(userObj.assigned_to, 'Applicable') }}">{{ getCount(userObj.assigned_to, 'Applicable') }}"</li>` to get the width for LI as I am trying to show it in line chart like above so, I will get the width multiply by 10 and %

Comment: yes, sort of, you need to remove the interpolation {{ }}, and keep only the expression inside - `'{{ getCount(userObj.assigned_to, 'Applicable') }}'`. something like: `[style.width.%]="getCount(userObj.assigned_to, 'Applicable') * 10"`

Comment: can you suggest me solution for this as well? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65357071/how-can-i-make-batchedit-available-for-json-nested-nodes-as-well

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like,

```
function getApplicableCounts() {
    return this.allUser.reduce((acc, curr) => {
        acc[curr.id] = curr.assigned_to.reduce((subAcc, subCurr) => {
            if (subCurr.sub_impact === 'Applicable') {
                subAcc.applicable++;
            } else if (subCurr.sub_impact === 'Not Applicable') {
                subAcc.notapplicable++;
            } else if (subCurr.sub_impact === 'FYI') {
                subAcc.fyi++;
            }
            return subAcc;
        }, {applicable:0, notapplicable:0, fyi: 0})
        return acc;
    }, {});
}
```

which should yield you the following result,

```
{
  '1': { applicable: 2, notapplicable: 1, fyi: 0 },
  '2': { applicable: 1, notapplicable: 1, fyi: 0 }
}
```

You can query it by `id` (I assume it's unique)

```
this.getApplicableCounts()[1]; // { applicable: 1, notapplicable: 1, fyi: 0 }
```

Comment: `getApplicableCounts() {
    this.impactCount = {applicable:0, notapplicable:0, fyi: 0}
    this.allUser.forEach(row => {
      row.assigned_to.forEach(sub => {
        if (sub.sub_impact === 'Applicable') {
          this.impactCount.applicable++;
        } else if (sub.sub_impact === 'Not Applicable') {
           this.impactCount.notapplicable++;
        } else if (sub.sub_impact === 'FYI') {
          this.impactCount.fyi++;
        }
      });
    });
  }` when i am updating with this function it's not showing up the result to me. please look into it n suggest me changes

Comment: I need to get the count only nodes of that parent but currently its giving me for all

Answer (score 0):

```
let indexPos = this.offset;
forEach(this.data, (data, index) => {
  indexPos += 1;
  data.sno = indexPos;
});

this.totalRecord = data.sno;
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply. [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/27780780)

Comment: I have updated my question for a better understanding