# How can I make batchEdit available for json nested nodes as well?

Tags: json, angular, typescript

Hi Stackoverflow Members

I wanted to make batch edit available for sub-nodes as well but I am not able to achieve it.

Can anyone please look into the code and suggest me the changes so, that batch edit is available for both parent node and nested node of record.

app.component.html

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <!-- Add Record -->
  <div *ngIf="isAdd">
    <form #myForm="ngForm">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>First Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="first_name" class="form-control" ngModel>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Last Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="last_name" class="form-control" ngModel>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Email</label>
        <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" ngModel>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Gender</label>
        <select name="gender" id="" ngModel class="form-control">
          <option>Male</option>
          <option>Female</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Date of Birth</label>
        <input type="date" name="dob" class="form-control" ngModel>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Impact</label>
        <div class="form-check">
          <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="impact" ngModel id="impactOption1" value="Applicable" checked>
          <label class="form-check-label" for="impactOption1">
            Applicable
          </label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-check">
          <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="impact" ngModel id="impactOption2" value="Not Applicable">
          <label class="form-check-label" for="impactOption2">
            Not Applicable
          </label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Score</label>
        <input type="number" name="score" class="form-control" ngModel>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" (click)="addUser(myForm.value)">Submit</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm ml-2" (click)="cancelAddUser()">Cancel</button>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
  <!-- Add Record -->
  <!-- Parent Batch Edit -->
  <div>
    <form #myForm="ngForm">
      <div class="form-group">
        <select name="impact" [disabled]="!isBatchEdit" class="form-control form-control-sm" [(ngModel)]="currentImpact">
          <option value="" disabled selected>Change Impact</option>
          <option>Applicable</option>
          <option>Not Applicable</option>
          <option>FYI</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <button type="button" [disabled]="!isBatchEdit" (click)="batchUpdateUser(); myForm.reset()" class="btn btn-success btn-sm btn-update mr-2">
        Update
        </button>
      <button type="button" [disabled]="!isBatchEdit" (click)="cancelBatchEdit(); myForm.reset()" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm">Cancel</button>
    </form>
  </div>
  <!-- Parent Batch Edit -->
  <!-- Single Record Edit -->
  <div *ngIf="isEdit">
    <form #myForm="ngForm">
      <div class="form-group">
        <select name="impact" id="" class="form-control form-control-sm" [(ngModel)]="currentImpact">
          <option>Applicable</option>
          <option>Not Applicable</option>
          <option>FYI</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <button type="button" (click)="updateUser()" class="btn btn-success btn-sm btn-update mr-2" *ngIf="isEdit">Update</button>
      <button type="button" (click)="cancelEdit()" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm">Cancel</button>
    </form>
  </div>
  <!-- Single Record Edit -->
  <!-- Filter -->
  <div class="filter-data mt-3">
    <form #form="ngForm">
      <div class="form-group float-left mr-4">
        <strong>Gender</strong>
        <br>
        <select class="form-control form-control-sm" name="gender" ngModel [ngModelOptions]="{updateOn: 'submit'}">
          <option></option>
          <option value="Male">Male</option>
          <option value="Female">Female</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group float-left">
        <strong>Impact</strong>
        <br>
        <select class="form-control form-control-sm" name="impact" ngModel [ngModelOptions]="{updateOn: 'submit'}">
          <option></option>
          <option value="Applicable">Applicable</option>
          <option value="Not Applicable">Not Applicable</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group float-left mt-3 pt-1 ml-2">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm mr-2">Apply</button>
        <button type="button" (click)="form.reset();" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm">Reset</button>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
  <!-- Filter -->
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
  <!-- Parent View Table -->
  <div class="viewData">
    <div class="float-left">
      <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm mb-2 mt-2" (click)="showAddUser()">Add New Record</button>
    </div>
    <div class="float-right">
      <div class="text-right total-records float-right">Total: {{totalRecords}}</div>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-secondary float-right mr-2 mt-2 mb-2" (click)="reload()">Refresh</button>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
    <table class="table table-sm table-responsive">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th></th>
          <th>First Name</th>
          <th>Last Name</th>
          <th>Email</th>
          <th>Gender</th>
          <th>DOB</th>
          <th>Impact</th>
          <th>Score</th>
          <th></th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr class="record-row" (click)="viewUser(user)" *ngFor="let user of allUser | tableFilter: form.value | paginate: { id: 'listing_pagination', itemsPerPage: 10, currentPage: page, totalItems: totalRecords }">
          <td><input *ngIf="!isEdit" [(ngModel)]="user.checked" type="checkbox" (change)="checkboxClicked()"></td>
          <td>{{user.first_name}}</td>
          <td>{{user.last_name}}</td>
          <td>{{user.email}}</td>
          <td>{{user.gender}}</td>
          <td>{{user.dob}}</td>
          <td>{{user.impact}}</td>
          <td>
            <div [ngClass]="getClass(user)">{{user.score}}</div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <button *ngIf="!isEdit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" (click)="editUser(user)">Edit</button>
            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm btn-sm ml-2" (click)="deleteUser(user)">Delete</button>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <pagination-controls id="listing_pagination" directionLinks="true" (pageChange)="page = $event"></pagination-controls>
  </div>
  <!-- Parent View Table -->
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
  <!-- Record Detail View -->
  <div *ngIf="isView" class="view-details">
    <ul class="card p-2">
      <li><strong>First Name</strong> <br />{{userObj.first_name}}</li>
      <li><strong>Last Name</strong> <br />{{userObj.last_name}}</li>
      <li><strong>Email</strong> <br />{{userObj.email}}</li>
      <li><strong>Gender</strong> <br />{{userObj.gender}}</li>
      <li><strong>IP Address</strong> <br />{{userObj.dob}}</li>
      <li><strong>Impact</strong> <br />{{userObj.impact}}</li>
      <li><strong>Score</strong> <br /><span [ngClass]="getClass(userObj)">{{userObj.score}}</span></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
    <div class="mb-3">
      <form #myForm="ngForm">
        <div class="form-group">
          <select name="impact" [disabled]="!isSubBatchEdit" class="form-control form-control-sm" [(ngModel)]="currentImpact">
            <option value="" disabled selected>Change Impact</option>
            <option>Applicable</option>
            <option>Not Applicable</option>
            <option>FYI</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <button type="button" [disabled]="!isSubBatchEdit" (click)="subBatchUpdateUser(); myForm.reset()" class="btn btn-success btn-sm btn-update mr-2">
          Update
          </button>
        <button type="button" [disabled]="!isSubBatchEdit" (click)="subCancelBatchEdit(); myForm.reset()" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm">Cancel</button>
      </form>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
    <table class="table table-responsive table-sm">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th></th>
          <th>CO Score</th>
          <th>Distribution List</th>
          <th>Impact</th>
          <th>Comments</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let assignee of userObj.assigned_to">
          <td><input *ngIf="!isEdit" [(ngModel)]="assignee.checked" type="checkbox" (change)="subCheckboxClicked()"></td>
          <td><div [ngClass]="getClass(assignee)">{{assignee.co_score}}</div></td>
          <td>{{assignee.dl}}</td>
          <td>{{assignee.sub_impact}}</td>
          <td>{{assignee.comments}}</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
    <div class="viewChart">
      <div class="skills">
        <ul class="labels">
          <li>Applicable</li>
          <li>Not Applicable</li>
          <li>FYI</li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="lines">
          <li class="line l--0"><span class="line__label">0</span></li>
          <li class="line l--1"><span class="line__label">1</span></li>
          <li class="line l--2"><span class="line__label">2</span></li>
          <li class="line l--3"><span class="line__label">3</span></li>
          <li class="line l--4"><span class="line__label">4</span></li>
          <li class="line l--5"><span class="line__label">5</span></li>
          <li class="line l--6"><span class="line__label">6</span></li>
          <li class="line l--7"><span class="line__label">7</span></li>
          <li class="line l--8"><span class="line__label">8</span></li>
          <li class="line l--9"><span class="line__label">9</span></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="charts">
          <div class="chart chart--dev">
            <ul class="charts--horiz">
              <li class="chart__bar" [style.width]="impactCount.applicable * 10 + '%'">{{impactCount.applicable}}</li>
              <li class="chart__bar" [style.width]="impactCount.notapplicable * 10 + '%'">{{impactCount.notapplicable}}</li>
              <li class="chart__bar" [style.width]="impactCount.fyi * 10 + '%'">{{impactCount.fyi}}</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Record Detail View -->
</div>
```

app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonService } from './common.service';
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})

export class AppComponent {
  title = 'db-poc1';
  allUser: any;
  isEdit = false;
  isView = false;
  isBatchEdit = false;
  isSubBatchEdit = false;
  isAdd = false;
  totalRecords: any;
  page: Number = 1;
  currentImpact: string = '';
  batchUpdateUsers = [];
  subBatchUpdateUsers = [];

  userObj = {
    id: '', first_name: '', last_name: '', email: '', gender: '', dob: '', impact: '', score: ''
  }

  impactCount = {
    applicable: 0, notapplicable: 0, fyi: 0 
  }

  constructor(private commonService: CommonService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getLatestUser();
  }

  reload() {
    window.location.reload();
  }

  checkboxClicked() {
    this.batchUpdateUsers = this.allUser.filter((row: any) => row.checked);
    this.isView  = true;
    this.isBatchEdit = this.batchUpdateUsers.length > 0;
    this.currentImpact = this.userObj.impact;
  }

  subCheckboxClicked() {
    this.subBatchUpdateUsers = this.allUser.filter((row: any) => row.checked);    
    this.isView  = true;
    this.isSubBatchEdit = this.subBatchUpdateUsers.length > 0;
    this.currentImpact = this.userObj.impact;
  }

  addUser(formObj: any) {
    this.commonService.createUser(formObj).subscribe((response) => {
      this.getLatestUser();
    });
    this.isAdd = false;
  }

  showAddUser() {
    this.isAdd = true;
  }
  
  cancelAddUser() {
    this.isAdd = false;
  }

  getLatestUser() {
    this.commonService.getAllUser().subscribe((response) => {
      this.allUser = response;
      this.totalRecords = this.allUser.length;
      this.getApplicableCounts();
      this.allUser.forEach((row: any) => row.checked = false);
    });
  }

  getApplicableCounts() {
    this.impactCount = {applicable:0, notapplicable:0, fyi: 0}
    this.allUser.forEach((row: any) => {
      // this.allUser.forEach(row => {
      //   if (row.impact === 'Applicable') {
      //     this.impactCount.applicable++;
      //   } else if (row.impact === 'Not Applicable') {
      //     this.impactCount.notapplicable++;
      //   } else if (row.impact === 'FYI') {
      //     this.impactCount.fyi++;
      //   }
      // });
      row.assigned_to.forEach((sub: any) => {
        if (sub.sub_impact === 'Applicable') {
          this.impactCount.applicable++;
        } else if (sub.sub_impact === 'Not Applicable') {
          this.impactCount.notapplicable++;
        } else if (sub.sub_impact === 'FYI') {
          this.impactCount.fyi++;
        }
      });
    });
  }

  editUser(user: any) {
    this.isEdit = true;
    this.userObj = user;
    this.allUser.forEach(user => user.checked = false);
    this.currentImpact = user.impact;
  }

  deleteUser(user: any) {
    this.commonService.deleteUser(user).subscribe(() => {
      this.getLatestUser();
    });
  }

  updateUser() {
    this.isEdit = !this.isEdit;
    this.userObj.impact = this.currentImpact;
    this.commonService.updateUser(this.userObj).subscribe(() => {
      this.getLatestUser();
    });
    this.getApplicableCounts();
  }

  cancelEdit() {
    this.isEdit = false;
    this.isView = false;
  }

  viewUser(user: any) {
    this.isView = true;
    this.userObj = user;
  }

  cancelBatchEdit() {
    this.isBatchEdit = false;
    this.allUser.forEach((user: any) => {user.checked = false});
  }

  getClass(user) {
    if(user.score <= 30 || user.co_score <= 30)
    return 'beginner';
    else if (user.score <= 75 || user.co_score <= 75)
    return 'intermediate';
    else if (user.score <= 100 || user.co_score <= 100)
    return 'expert';
    else return 'other';
  }

  batchUpdateUser() {
    this.isBatchEdit = false;
    const batchUpdateUserList = [];
    this.allUser.forEach((user: any) => {
      if (user.checked) {
        user.impact = this.currentImpact
        batchUpdateUserList.push(user);
        user.checked = false;
        this.commonService.updateUser(user).subscribe(() => {
          this.getLatestUser();
        });
        user.score = "Updated";
      }
    });
    this.commonService.updateUser(this.userObj).subscribe(() => {
      this.getLatestUser();
    });
    this.getApplicableCounts();
  }

  subBatchUpdateUser() {
    this.isSubBatchEdit = false;
    const subBatchUpdateUserList = [];
    this.allUser.forEach((user: any) => {
      if (user.sub_impact.checked) {
        user.sub_impact.impact = this.currentImpact
        subBatchUpdateUserList.push(user);
        user.sub_impact.checked = false;
        this.commonService.updateUser(user).subscribe(() => {
          this.getLatestUser();
        });
        user.score = "Updated";
      }
    });
    this.commonService.updateUser(this.userObj).subscribe(() => {
      this.getLatestUser();
    });
    this.getApplicableCounts();
  }

  subCancelBatchEdit() {
    this.isSubBatchEdit = false;
    this.allUser.forEach((user: any) => {user.checked = false});
  }
}
```

db.json

```
{
  "users": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "first_name": "Male",
      "last_name": "Record",
      "email": "male.record@gmail.com",
      "gender": "Male",
      "dob": "01-01-1987",
      "impact": "Not Applicable",
      "score": "Updated",
      "checked": false,
      "assigned_to": [
        {
          "co_score": 54,
          "dl": "CAT1",
          "sub_impact": "Applicable",
          "checked": false,
          "comments": "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book."
        },
        {
          "co_score": 20,
          "dl": "CAT2",
          "sub_impact": "Not Applicable",
          "checked": false,
          "comments": "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book."
        },
        {
          "co_score": 99,
          "dl": "CAT1",
          "sub_impact": "Applicable",
          "checked": false,
          "comments": "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book."
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "first_name": "Female",
      "last_name": "Record",
      "email": "female.record@gmail.com",
      "gender": "Female",
      "dob": "31-12-1987",
      "impact": "Applicable",
      "checked": false,
      "score": "Updated",
      "assigned_to": [
        {
          "co_score": 54,
          "dl": "CAT1",
          "sub_impact": "Applicable",
          "checked": false,
          "comments": "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book."
        },
        {
          "co_score": 20,
          "dl": "CAT2",
          "sub_impact": "Not Applicable",
          "checked": false,
          "comments": "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book."
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "first_name": "Male",
      "last_name": "Record Another",
      "email": "male.recordanother@gmail.com",
      "gender": "Male",
      "dob": "31-10-2017",
      "impact": "Applicable",
      "checked": false,
      "score": 25,
      "assigned_to": [
        {
          "co_score": 100,
          "dl": "CAT3",
          "sub_impact": "Applicable",
          "checked": false,
          "comments": "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book."
        },
        {
          "co_score": 2,
          "dl": "CAT2",
          "sub_impact": "Not Applicable",
          "checked": false,
          "comments": "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book."
        },
        {
          "co_score": 48,
          "dl": "CAT2",
          "sub_impact": "Not Applicable",
          "checked": false,
          "comments": "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book."
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "first_name": "Male",
      "last_name": "One More Record",
      "email": "male.onemorerecord@gmail.com",
      "gender": "Male",
      "dob": "08-08-1984",
      "impact": "Applicable",
      "id": 6,
      "checked": false,
      "score": "Updated",
      "assigned_to": [
        {
          "co_score": 4,
          "dl": "CAT1",
          "sub_impact": "Applicable",
          "checked": false,
          "comments": "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book."
        },
        {
          "co_score": 85,
          "dl": "CAT3",
          "sub_impact": "Not Applicable",
          "checked": false,
          "comments": "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book."
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "first_name": "Female",
      "last_name": "Another Record",
      "email": "female.anotherrecord@gmail.com",
      "gender": "Female",
      "dob": "2000-07-15",
      "impact": "Applicable",
      "id": 7,
      "checked": false,
      "score": 85,
      "assigned_to": [
        {
          "co_score": 34,
          "dl": "CAT3",
          "sub_impact": "Applicable",
          "checked": false,
          "comments": "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book."
        },
        {
          "co_score": 55,
          "dl": "CAT2",
          "sub_impact": "Not Applicable",
          "checked": false,
          "comments": "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book."
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 8,
      "first_name": "New",
      "last_name": "Record",
      "email": "new.record@gmail.com",
      "gender": "Male",
      "dob": "2020-12-17",
      "impact": "Not Applicable",
      "score": 60,
      "checked": false,
      "assigned_to": [
        {
          "co_score": 94,
          "dl": "CAT1",
          "sub_impact": "Not Applicable",
          "checked": false,
          "comments": "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book."
        },
        {
          "co_score": 85,
          "dl": "CAT3",
          "sub_impact": "Applicable",
          "checked": false,
          "comments": "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book."
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: https://angular-ivy-3iaw11.stackblitz.io/

Comment: its unclear to me what you want to batch edit exactly

Comment: @Moshezauros i have batch selection and update for the parent node but i wanted to do the same for nested nodes as well.. so, there will be 2 batch operations one for parent which will work separetly (which is working fine) and one for nested/child records so, that user can update their impacts as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of ways to implement this, one way is something like:

in your template:

```
<tr *ngFor="let assignee of userObj.assigned_to">
    <td><input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="assignee.checked"></td>
    <td>{{assignee.sub_impact}}</td>
</tr>
```

and in your component:

```
updateUser() {
    this.isView = !this.isView;
    this.isEdit = !this.isEdit;
    this.userObj.impact = this.currentImpact;

    debugger;
    const checkedItems = this.userObj.assigned_to.filter(a => a.checked);
    checkedItems.forEach(a => {
      a.sub_impact = this.currentImpact;
      delete a.checked;
    });

    console.log("update");
    //this.commonService.updateUser().subscribe(response => {
    this.getCounts();
    //});
  }
```

notice that if you want different values between the user obj and the assigned_to you will have to create a new dropdown

here is a working [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-h7jkgj?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

[image]

[image]

Comment: @Moshezaurous this is not updating the sub records rather it's working for parent

Comment: @KunalVijan check the stackblitz I just added, if this is not what you are after, then you need to explain again

Comment: thanks for looking into it. I need to update the impact for sub records as well like it's updating for parent one. When select any/multiple record it shows a select with applicable n not applicable option, same I want for child record as user will select show option to change the impact to applicable or not applicable n post to service. I hope it's clear now

Comment: I don't understand how is that different than what happens in the stackblitz I posted

Comment: the one which you have posted is not showing up the select control if we will select child element checkbox. maybe you might have missed saving it can you please check it again?  https://angular-ivy-h7jkgj.stackblitz.io/ I don't have any option to change the impact for sub records

Comment: @KunalVijan I was using the same select for both, updated it, check again

Comment: attached screenshots of what I am seeing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226184/discussion-between-kunal-vijan-and-moshezauros).